# NSEntityDescription name Optional

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data, nsentitydescription

I have an instance of [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription) that I obtained through the [`entity()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640588-entity) method on the class of an [`NSManagedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject) subclass. I want to get its [`name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsentitydescription/1425101-name), but the type of that property is `String?` rather than just `String`

```swift
let entityName: String = MyManagedObjectSubclass.entity().name // Error: Must be unwrapped
```

Under what circumstances would the `name` be `nil`? Is it safe to force-unwrap in this context? I have yet to see it return `nil`, but I'd like to make sure I'm appropriately handling whatever case would cause that to happen

Comment: I'd tend to say that's because when you create it, it can be done "property by property". Ie, if you have already a model set and a persistent coordinator, it should be fine.